# Animate image size

Tags: android, image

I would like to have an image "bump" (or change its size) according to music. I don't need the music detect side, I just need a way to resize the image dymaically and according to an animation. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using at least API 11 and want to animate it smoothly, you can use an `ObjectAnimator` to animate various changes to the properties of a `View`. For example:

```
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, View.SCALE_X, 1.0, 1.25);
oa.setDuration(25); //how long the animation lasts in ms, probably short for your purposes
oa.start();
```

This will scale the X size of the view `myView` from the default (1.0) to slightly larger (1.25). You will then need to do the same for the `SCALE_Y` property. Note that you will probably want to keep track of the current scale value so that your next animations look nice. For example:

```
float currentScale = 1.0;
...
void scaleMyView(float newScale) {
    ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, View.SCALE_X, currentScale, newScale);
    oa.setDuration(25);
    oa.start();
    currentScale = newScale;
}
```

See also the documentation on [`ObjectAnimators`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) if you need more info. Hope this helps!

Comment: Considering that he just needs the image to 'pop' to different sizes according to music, which can be very fast paced, I don't think this is a very good approach.

Comment: @ArkayCZ Since the OP didn't specify exactly what their algorithm does, it could possibly be useful in some way. I agree, however, if it is being used to "pop" the image based on the current relative volume of the song (for example) your method is best. However, if it is something that is slower updating (for an example off the top of my head, those visualizer bars that instantly grow then slowly shrink based on maximum volume of a channel recently... poorly described, sorry) then this might be useful. I figured I'd just put it out there and the OP can decide what works best for their app.

Comment: I suppose that's true. And it never hurts to learn something extra.

Comment: Oh... that's it... I used to use it long time ago and forgot it :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Every `View` has `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` methods. I believe you can use it for this. As far as syncing it to the music, that depends on the way you're playing it.

Comment: Yep but in my particular case animation is better, this is a good answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

There is greate animation library for Android.
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations
https://github.com/2359media/EasyAndroidAnimations